# Adding values to database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am doing a project which is based on storing the employee details, like name, id, log in time and log out time. So I created a database to store the details of the employee, my problem is that i am getting the values dynamically from the user in different screens, i have problem with storing the values into the database. now am passing all the values into one screen and storing them in that class, even though i am not getting the log out time of the employee. Now am using the below code to add the values into database.

```
db.addDetails(new Contact(client_id, empn, timein, "6.30PM"));
```

Is there any way to store the values into database screen by screen for the same user?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this..

```
public long createemployee(String name) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
    values.put(sqlitehelper.COLUMN_NAME,name);
    long insertId = database.insert(sqlitehelper.LIBRARY, null,values);
     return insertId;
}
```

now put this in your first screen.. you will get the id of the entry in database.. now pass this id to next activities using intents..
then  in next activity store time in value like this into database..and all other values can be updated in similar way in respective activities.. on passing the id from first activity

```
String strFilter = "_id=" + Id;<--- id from first activity
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(TIME_IN,TIME);
myDB.update(sqlitehelper.LIBRARY, args, strFilter, null);
```

Comment: i can't get you. can u explain with an example

Comment: I was telling that.. in first page.. suppose you are getting the name of the employee... then create a new row with that name.. and all fields will be empty then... now you get the id of that row from **"return insertId"** ... now pass this id value to next class..and update the columns in that row.. as you get required values one by one.. here you should always pass the id to the next class

Comment: you mean adding first value and keeping all blank and updating the row whenever we want to insert more? like this? 
db.addDetails(new Contact(client_id, "", "", ""));

Comment: yes...or.. if you have ut that these fields cannot be null.. while creating you database.. you can use your default values also.. and later update them..

Comment: hi raju, i got one more doubt while trying your code, when we modify the row in database, the all previous values must be included na? what i mean is, if u pass client_id in 1st screen, in the second u want to put Employee number, so when modifying db, we have to insert both client_id and Emp num? right?

Comment: when you are modifying a specific column of a row... you just need to pass the id of the row and the value of the column that should be changed.. so just id is enough..

Comment: yes.. i'll send u my Database code, can u show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea:

The user knows which dataset he want to edit/change/update.
So the identifier of a dataset in various ways is known to you. Possible ways:

- Select the item befor you start your activity and parse it by .putExtra() to the intent
- Let the user select which dataset he wants to edit on ativity start
- Let the user select, where to save the information he just created on save.

In short: The ID is always known to the Programm.

And therefore I would do something like

```
if (db.hasDataset(id)) {
    db.updateDataset(id, updatedInformation);    
} else
    db.createDataset(id, newDatasetInitInformation);
}
```

in db.updateDataset you use .update(...) whith a where clause like

> table.id=selectedId

The .update(...) function only update the values in your contentValues object. If values are missing, the remain unchanged.

in db.createDataset you just use .insert() in the way you supposently already do.

for further Information see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)